# Git Ignores Folder Without `.gitignore` Even Existing

Tags: git, smartgit

There is no `.gitignore` in the repository I'm using, nor is there one in my home directory.

I'm not using git for programming, here. Instead I want to figure out whether it's a good idea to use it for something else. Unfortunately, I ran into a problem which I only discovered because I checked out an empty branch but found files/folders (other than `$repo/.git`) in my repo.

Now, the files git has trouble with are in a really horribly named directory. It's `$repo/Google%20Photos/Hangout_%20Tauberfranken%20%ED%A0%BD%ED%B0%B8` in HTML notation and `47 6F 6F 67 6C 65 20 50 68 6F 74 6F 73 2F 48 61 6E 67 6F 75 74 5F 20 54 61 75 62 65 72 66 72 61 6E 6B 65 6E 20 ED A0 BD ED B0 B8` in hex (omitting `$repo/` for this one) and probably invalid in every text encoding whatsoever. Note that there is no `2F` nor a `00` in there and the file name length is far from 255 and bigger than 0, so I definitely operate within the specifications of ext4.

However, this shouldn't be a problem for git and certainly isn't a problem for ext4. I'm using SmartGit and don't even get an error message. The files in there are simply ignored.

Why is this happening and which characters should I avoid so it doesn't happen any more? (Yeah, I know that they probably at least should be valid UTF-8, but maybe there are more restrictions.)

Comment: Does it work with the command line client?

Comment: As I re-read your question, it appears that you have files in the horribly named directory. Could you `cd` into that directory and show a partial output of `ls -l` please? While you are in that directory, could you please do `git status` and add the output from command line?

Comment: @RyanO'Hara Thank you! If I use git on the command line, I can stage and commit the files in this folder. But after I launched SmartGit afterwards, things got even weirder. Now SmartGit shows me that these files (of whom it didn't know anything in the past) are allegedly missing. They definitely are in the file system and git gives me a nice "nothing to commit, working directory clean".

Comment: Is the repo inside a special location such as Windows\System32 ?, or Program Files ?

Comment: @M.M Would I be able to use such file names if I was a Windows user? ;-) (Or be talking about ext4.) I think the problem isn't git. git probably works just fine and the problem is SmartGit. My guess is that it modifies strings it reads from the git repo or the FS and then can't find these files when it looks for them the next time, so it doesn't list them as untracked and doesn't add them when committing everything. This also would explain why it listed them as missing after I added them using git on the console.

Comment: @UTF-8 Yes, you can use `Hangout_%20Tauberfranken%20%ED%A0%BD%ED%B0%B8` as a directory name in Windows. As far as SmartGit is concerned, there appears to be a bug in it from reading the behavior it is exhibiting. Could you try using http://www.collab.net/downloads/giteye and see how it performance in comparison with SmartGit?

Answer (score 0):

There might be no files in that directory - could you please double-check? Git tracks contents not directories. If there are no files to track, git status will show no change.

```
cd ~
mkdir repo
cd repo
mkdir -p Google%20Photos/Hangout_%20Tauberfranken%20%ED%A0%BD%ED%B0%B8

git init
Initialized empty Git repository in

git status
On branch master
Initial commit
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

Notice that even though we have a directory created with HTML encoding, git just goes along its merry way ignoring those directories ever existed. It is looking for content to track (e.g. text in files, binary data in files etc.). Since there is no file/content to track, git choose to ignore the presence of the directories.

```
cd Google%20Photos/Hangout_%20Tauberfranken%20%ED%A0%BD%ED%B0%B8/
vim test.txt
(wrote something in test.txt and saved it)

cd ~/repo

git status
On branch master
Initial commit
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        Google%20Photos/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Now that we added content, git is recognizing it and prompting us untracked files.